# Add data frame and extra rows to csv

Tags: r, csv, statistics

I have the following dataFrame:

```
n = c(2, 3, 5) 
s = c("aa", "bb", "cc") 
b = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE) 
df = data.frame(n, s, b) 

string1 <- paste("Length of result: " ,  length(df))
summary <- summary(df)

write.csv(df, file = "result.csv",row.names=TRUE, sep=',')
```

At the moment only the input of `df` is written. I would also like to add `string1` and `summary` to my `result.csv`. The best solution would be if I could have one empty row in between the results and the output.

Any recommendation how to add `string1` and `summary` to my `result.csv` file?

I appreciate your replies!

**UPDATE**

I tried the method from NealC and got:

[image]

This is basically wrong! I would like to get something like that:

[image]

Comment: I just want to point out that if you use `sep = ';'`, then the file won't end up being a csv, technically speaking.

Comment: What I would do is just import your results and then `cbind()` your data frame with the file then export again.

Comment: @NealC Thx for your answer! How exactly would this look like in R code?

Comment: Try `cat(rep("\n", 3), summary[,1], file = "result.csv", append = TRUE)` **after** your `write.csv()` call

Comment: @RichardScriven Thx this works perfectly! I would appreciate if you could add this as a detailed reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your `write.csv()` call, you can append to the csv with the following call to `cat()`.

```
cat("\n", "Freq", summary[,1], sep = "\n", append = TRUE, file = "result.csv")
```

In the above call, here's what's happening:

- first add an extra blank line with `"\n"`.
- then add the `"Freq"` line you requested above the summary
- next is `summary[,1]` for the `n` part of the summary
- then a newline separator `sep = "\n"`
- and finally `append = TRUE` is to append all this to the file `file = "result.csv"`

The resulting file looks like this:

```
"","n","s","b"
"1",2,"aa",TRUE
"2",3,"bb",FALSE
"3",5,"cc",TRUE


Freq
Min.   :2.000  
1st Qu.:2.500  
Median :3.000  
Mean   :3.333  
3rd Qu.:4.000  
Max.   :5.000
```

And to read these back into R separately, you can do

```
read.csv("result.csv", nrows = 3)
#   X n  s     b
# 1 1 2 aa  TRUE
# 2 2 3 bb FALSE
# 3 3 5 cc  TRUE
cat(scan("result.csv", skip = 5, what = "", sep="\n"), sep="\n")
# Freq
# Min.   :2.000  
# 1st Qu.:2.500  
# Median :3.000  
# Mean   :3.333  
# 3rd Qu.:4.000  
# Max.   :5.000
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you liked my suggestion, here's how I'd go about it.

`file <- read.csv(result.csv, sep=",")`

You can format the data more this way before you export it again, which is why I pick this over simply appending to the file which could cause errors anyways.

Then you want to cbind these together.

`newData <- rbind(file,df)`

Then do what you did in your code and export it again.

`write.csv(newData, file = "result.csv",row.names=TRUE, sep=';', row.names=FALSE)`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thx for your reply! I tried your method, however, I get the wrong result. Please have a look at my update!

Comment: Hey @mrquad , I saw your update. Try `rbind()` instead of cbind(). It's hard to know what someone wants with little code. This should help.

Comment: Thx for your answer! I tried `rbind`, but I still get the same result as before. Any suggestion what is wrong with bind?

Comment: Is it outputting the same? rbind means to combine the rows together vertically, and cbind does the column horizontally. It shouldn't be giving this output.

I'll be able to check more into it when I get home from work in the next hour and a half.